# Base station coverage analysis in QGIS

Tags: qgis, vector

I want to find base station coverage for a instant location. I have building data. And i determine optimum coverage as 500m far away from a base station (buffer). So how can i find optimum base station location for this example. Looks like that

[image]

Comment: Can you explain the scenario a little more.  Optimal on what?  What are the parameters that the optimal evaluation will be based on? Location, distance from, cost, etc.

Comment: I want to find just locations of base stations. The stations must cover all buildings. note a coverage distance of a base station is 500 m diameter.

Comment: I'm sorry, but that didn't clarify anything.  Stations usually mean points, so stations for each building would be a centroid for each building.  A coverage usually means a polygon, so if you need coverage of the stations you would buffer them.  You need to identify what is optimal.  Is this for rounting? Location placement identification?

Comment: You are right stations are points. I want to find each base station point. But every station have coverage area. It is 500m diameter. So i must find optimal base station locations that cover all buildings and they must be minimum number.

Comment: So if I get you right, you want to reduce the overlap, but ensure there are no gaps?